# How to convert a Redis ArrayRedisResult into a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

I would like to convert an array table returned by Redis to be used in my C# code. How can I do that ?

After debugging the code, I can see that he returns an `ArrayRedisResult`

```
string script = @"return redis.call('HGETALL', @key)";
LuaScript lScript = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
var lLScript = lScript.Load("myServerinformation");
var result = lLScript.Evaluate("myDatabaseInformation", "myKey");
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from other answer where OP said in some comment:

> the million dollars question is how to convert it to a type array that
>   C# will understand?

You'll cry when you realize that your question has a very easy answer: `ArrayRedisResult` can be casted to a lot of array types: `string[]`, `bool[]`... [Check its source code.](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/b96f49730aff67ee57424ab5b9e189ae4b379d47/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisResult.cs#L183)

At the end of the day, it's just about coding an explicit cast:

```
var result = (string[])lLScript.Evaluate("myDatabaseInformation", "myKey");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Truly the answer wasn't far.

Comment: @eddy0223 Yeah. We should ask Marc Gravell to know why he decided to implement these operators as *explicit* instead of *implicit*. With implicit operators, you could type the result as `string[]` and you wouldn't need an explicit cast ;P